# How to properly access a VR website with a Htc Vive pro?

Tags: three.js, aframe

I'm not able to have a correct immersive VR experience with Aframe and a HTC Vive pro.

**Context :**

With steamVr, I'm Able to access the VR website from the desktop navigation > chrome or firefox.
Which is basically a curved screen/desktop.

but how can I have the same experience as a standalone application ?

**What I am trying to achieve :**

I want to provide a full immersive mode as I have with a standalone application. 
In steamVr environnement, I still have a curved browser in front of me (even with Vr button pressed).

I didn't find a good explanation on how to access a VR website.

Comment: SteamVR/HTC Vive seems currently not supported on latest Chrome, see https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1088046.

Comment: As daydream is no longer maintain by Google maybe aframe will desappear.

Comment: SteamVR not working in Chrome is temporary. Compatibility is expected in future versions.